# Simple require-jquery test not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Why won't this simple require-jquery test show an alert?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

stuff.

<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require-jquery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

js/main.js:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(function() {
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

No errors or anything, and no alert. I also tried putting the script tag in the head, but didn't make a difference. :(

The js files exist and are directly accessible from a browser.

**Edit:**
Oops! This seems to be a caching issue, where an old cached (non-working) version of the js was being loaded instead. After reloading the page several times quickly, it seemed to work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried simply calling the alert inside the callback? Like:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: Oops, turns out it was a caching issue! Thanks anyway.